# Multidimensional arrays java

Tags: java, sorting, multidimensional-array, bubble-sort

can someone help me?
I am new at java programming and don't know how to make bubble sort for multidimensional array. I am trying to obtain sortes array{{1, 8, 48, 55}, {75, 88, 98, 103} }
It is my code:

```
int[][] arr2 = {{98,8,103,55}, {88,48,75,1}};

    for (int i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < arr2[i].length; j++) 
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < arr2[i].length; k++)
            {
                for (int l = 0; l < arr2[j].length; l++)
                {
                    if(arr2[j][l] > arr2[j][l+1])
                    {
                        int tmp = arr2[j][l];
                        arr2[j][l] = arr2[j][l+1];
                        arr2[j][l+1] = tmp;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And I have gotten a message with an error "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4"

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What result are you trying to obtain? How is your code actually behaving that's different from that? From the [Help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): "Questions seeking debugging help ("_why isn't this code working?_") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)."

Comment: I am trying to obtain {{1, 8, 48, 55}, {75, 88, 98, 103} }

Comment: Please edit your question to include that information along with information about what your code actually produces, as the Help center guidelines describe. Also, include an explanation of how the output should be derived from the input. It's far from obvious what the relationship is that you want to implement.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int l = 0; l < arr2[j].length; l++)
```

l loops up to the maximum index of arr2[j].

```
if(arr2[j][l] > arr2[j][l+1])

arr2[j][l] = arr2[j][l+1];
```

Last iteration of the previously mentioned loop is now guaranteed to crash because l+1 is automatically out of bounds, seeing as you didn't modify it within the loop.